# Чтение из dev/usb/lp0 в Linux

Tags: linux, usb, label, принтер

Есть принтер меток, чтобы выслать файл на печать достаточно сделать cat file.prn > /dev/usb/lp0. Мне нужно получить ответ от принтера, Device Monitoring Studio на Win7 показывает, что ответ от принтера приходит и выглядит так RET33:Test.prn|Box.prn|Line.prn. Как на linux получить этот ответ?

Comment: надо прочитать из файла — так читайте. суть вопроса не ясна.

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте наоборот: * cat /dev/usb/lp0  >  responce.txt*.  Но что-то мне подсказывает, что ничего хорошего из этого не получится.  Надо проверить, принимается ли ответ от принтера и в какой момент, если принимается. Для этого можно использовать **tcpdump**. Вот здесь очень хорошо описано, как это сделать: https://technolinchpin.wordpress.com/2015/10/23/usb-bus-sniffers-for-linux-system/

Comment: Ну вначале запускаете процесс чтения ответа, **после** — уже записи. Это должно быть два разных процесса, работающих параллельно.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в том и вопрос, как прочитать? какая команда для чтения?

Comment: @0andriy можешь показать, как выглядят команды запуска процессов чтения и записи

Comment: @Sergey ответ приходит, когда принтер начинает печатать

Comment: эта секретная команда вам отлично известна — вы её привели прямо в тексте вопроса: `$ cat файл`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Под файлом имеется ввиду файл, в котором будут храниться входные данные или файл точки монтирования /dev/usb/lp0?

Comment: Мне нечего добавить к комментарию @alexanderbarakin ;-) `cat` на соответствующий файл в */dev/usb/*.

Comment: @0andriy попробовал так сделать, запустил процесс cat /dev/usb/lp0 ,а в другом терминале выслал файл на принтер и выдало, что устройство занято

Comment: @Илья Кузьмич **ответ приходит, когда принтер начинает печатать** - это Вы исходя из экспериментов в винде утверждаете, или *tcpdump* так показала?

Comment: @Sergey да, в винде эксперементировал и смотрел программой Device Monitoring Studio. что высылает, а что принимает. Еще на языке принтера высылал запросы без печати, чтобы к примеру получить объем занятой памяти

Comment: Что вам мешает настроить CUPS с соответствующим драйвером принтера?

Comment: @0andriy потому что в cups нет принтера wincode, есть только zebra(из принтеров этикеток). Раньше я печатал с помощью cups и драйвер был выбран для zebra, но первое задание на печать он высылал быстро на принтер, а последующие с проблемами, такими как задержка на 5 и более минут, мог начать предыдущие задания печать вместо актуальных и т.д.

Comment: @Илья Кузьмич **в винде эксперементировал** - поэтому я рекомендую, проверить его наличие в линухе с помощью *tctpdump*. Давайте начнём с простого - а был ли мальчик?

Comment: @Sergey установить tcpdump не было проблемой, но к сожалению встроенного usbmon в ядро на raspberry нет

Comment: @Илья Кузьмич **встроенного usbmon** - так ведь и не должно быть! Он должен быть в виде модуля. Поэтому в инструкции написано, что надо выполнить команду: *modprobe usbmon*. Но, насчёт малинки я не знаю. Там может быть даже в виде модуля нет.

Если его нет даже в виде модуля, имеет смысл попробовать получить хоть какой-то минимум информации. Попробуйте выполнить команду *lsof > list1.txt* при отключеном принтере. Потом запустите принтер и выполните *lsof > list2.txt*. Потом сравните эти файлы хотя бы, с помощью *meld*. Сразу увидите, какие файлы используются в процессе печати.

Comment: @Sergey usbmon удалось вчера установить, но выдает, что отсутствует файл /data/usblog.pcap и wireshark требует наличие графического интерфейса, а у меня система без нее(dietpi). С помощью lsof проверил, отличается процессами, proc/5358 вместо proc/5357

Comment: @Sergey в другом месте создал этот файл, но в нем только та информация, которую я высылаю, ответа с принтера нет

Comment: @Илья Кузьмич "выдает, что отсутствует файл /data/usblog.pcap". Я не понимаю, о чём Вы говорите. В корне файловой системы нет (и, насколько я знаю) не должно быть каталаго */data*.  И зачем Вы пытаетесь запустить *wireshark* ? Это же программа с GUI. Ещё раз рекомендую попробовать *tcpdump*. Это утилита командной строки.

Comment: @Sergey я позже отписал, что удалось запустить tcpdump и вывод в .pcap файл сделать. Так вот, прикол в том, что внутри файла только то, что я высылаю на принтер, а ответа с принтера в этом файле нет

Comment: @Илья Кузьмич *ответа с принтера в этом файле нет*. Получается, что один и тот же принтер, под виндой посылает ответ, а под люнихом - нет. Вижу только одну возможную причину: драйвер под люнихом инициализирует устройство иначе, чем виндовозный. И принтер просто не посылает сообщение. Вы каким драйвером пользуетесь? Попробуйте найти на сайте производителя драйвер этого принтера под люних.